# Include a blade with controller in all pages in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, include, laravel-blade

I have a bootstrap navigation which should be easily modified from admin panel. Currently I include that navigation blade and it's impossible to add/remove elements from navigation without changing the blade file.

How can I include a navigation controller which returns blade file in a page?

To visualise:

```
 Page controller
    Page blade
        Navigation controller
            Navigation blade
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a controller on a blade template would break the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern on which Laravel is built-on hence its impossible to have the structure that you want above.

My suggestion is to break down the navigation blade to smaller blade templates and depending on what you want to show pass different variables to the blade template. Then use

```
@if(variable ==true)
  @include('small.navigation.blade')
@endif
```

You can use the if statements to control what can be seen or not. Hence the modification of navigation panel from admin side would involve set of variables that govern navigation and whether they are present or not.